# How to notify Elsevier or Clarivate when then they are indexing predatory or very low quality journals?

Tags: elsevier, scopus, web-of-science

What is the best way to alert Elsevier or Clarivate Analytics -- for instance, if I see a potentially predatory (or just really low quality) journal indexed in Scopus or WoS or if I see recent changes that possibly indicate a lowering of standards by the journal (such as a dramatic increase in the number of articles published)?

Comment: I don't see any reason for you to do anything. Let Clarivate Analytics care about their product by themselves. Your input isn't necessary and probably not even welcome.

Comment: @Roland Many of these indexes form the basis of university rankings (I.e., how many articles is the university getting in listed journals) which influences university prestige, which in turn influences academic incentives, promotions, and rewards. So even if you object to such a system, surely it is better for such indexes to reflect valid journals.

Answer (score 5):

First, Elsevier or Clarivate Analytics already monitor things like dramatic increases in the number of articles published. It's why excessive self-citation can and has lead to journals getting delisted.

However you can still write to them to highlight potential problems. If you want to do this, the best way is to use their "contact us" forms on their website. [Here's Scopus's page on it](https://service.elsevier.com/app/overview/scopus/), and [here's Web of Science's](https://clarivate.com/contact-us/support/?language=en_US). Be prepared for the exchange to go like any other investigation - you may be asked to provide proof.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on indices and metrics to judge the quality of a journal.  Rely on the journal content and on colleagues who have experience with the journal's review practices.  There is no reason to alert any index.

If your library is paying for the publication, you might suggest the librarian bring it up with the publisher's sales staff.

Comment: This is not about judging the quality of the journal. The problems arise if people are judged based on their citation reports and the IF of the journals they are publishing in, which is often the case if applying for grants, scholarships or positions (Not saying this is a good way to do this but it's how it's done). If predatory journals are included in these citation reports then people who publish there get better records...